# Is there any way to retrieve the name for a gist that github displays

Tags: github-api, gist

When I browse to a gist on gist.github.com it displays a friendly name. E.g. for
https://gist.github.com/stuartleeks/1f4e07546db69b15ade2 it shows stuartleeks/baz

This seems to be determined by the first file that it shows in the list of files for the gist, but I was wondering whether there is any way to retrieve this via the API?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you [can get with the Gist API the JSON information associated to a gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist), reusing the id of your url:

```
GET /gists/:id
```

In your case: https://api.github.com/gists/1f4e07546db69b15ade2

It includes:

```
"files": {
    "baz": {
      "filename": "baz",
```

and:

```
"owner": {
    "login": "stuartleeks",
```

That should be enough to infer the name `stuartleeks/baz`.

Comment: Further, since the files attribute returns an object (which is inherently unordered by the RFC) your language may read it into an unordered structure. So you want the file name that is alphabetically first.